# How to get the Unicode code point for a character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I'm using a barcode scanner to read a barcode on my website (the website is made in OpenUI5).

The scanner works like a keyboard that types the characters it reads. At the end and the beginning of the typing it uses a special character. These characters are different for every type of scanner.

Some possible characters are:

- █
- ▄
- –
- —

In my code I use `if (oModelScanner.oData.scanning && oEvent.key == "\u2584")` to check if the input from the scanner is ▄.

Is there any way to get the code from that character in the \uHHHH style? (with the HHHH being the hexadecimal code for the character)

I tried the [charCodeAt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charCodeAt.asp) but this returns the decimal code.

With the [codePointAt examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt#Examples) they make the code I need into a decimal code so I need a reverse of this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Javascript strings have a method [codePointAt](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/codepointat) which gives you the integer representing the Unicode point value. You need to use a base 16 (hexadecimal) representation of that number if you wish to format the integer into a four hexadecimal digits sequence (as in the response of Nikolay Spasov).

```
var hex = "▄".codePointAt(0).toString(16);
var result = "\\u" + "0000".substring(0, 4 - hex.length) + hex;
```

However it would probably be easier for you to check directly if you key code point integer match the expected code point

```
oEvent.key.codePointAt(0) === '▄'.codePointAt(0);
```

Note that "symbol equality" can actually be trickier: some symbols are defined by surrogate pairs (you can see it as the combination of two halves defined as four hexadecimal digits sequence).

For this reason I would recommend to use a specialized library.

you'll find more details in the very [relevant article by Mathias Bynens](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode)

Comment: `codePointAt` does not return the code point _in decimal_. It returns _just the number_. Whether it is decimal or hexadecimal only becomes relevant later, when that number is printed somewhere.

Comment: This is correct: a number has a given value independently of the base used by one of its  representation. However in the context of comparison the representation of a number is important as well, for example: 56 !== 0x56 (86) but more importantly '\u0056'.codePointAt(0) !== 56, which is often confusing

Comment: What if your codepoint is greater than `FFFF`? For example, `''.codePointAt(0).toString(16)` returns 
`'1000a'`

Answer (score 8):

If you want to print the multiple code points of a character, e.g., an emoji, you can do this:

```js
const facepalmWithExtraAttributes = "‍♂️"; // sex, skin, etc
const codePoints = Array.from(facepalmWithExtraAttributes)
  .map((character) => character.codePointAt(0).toString(16))
  .map((hex) => "\\u{" + hex + "}");
console.log({
  facepalmWithExtraAttributes,
  codePoints
}); // {   "facepalmWithExtraAttributes": "\u200d♂️",   "codePoints": [     "\\u{1f926}",     "\\u{1f3fc}",      "\\u{200d}",    "\\u{2642}",    "\\u{fe0f}"  ] }
```

If you are wondering about the components and the length of ‍♂️, check out [this article](https://hsivonen.fi/string-length/).

Answer (score 6):

```
var hex = "▄".charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
var result = "\\u" + "0000".substring(0, 4 - hex.length) + hex;
```